# What is netblocks size in a host?

Tags: security, host

I entered a domain [here](http://zulu.zscaler.com/) and I see that they checked the host's netblocks size. What is a *netblocks size*?

Answer (score 0):

They are referring to how many IP addresses are in use by the domain. Here is a chart.. https://www.ripe.net/about-us/press-centre/IPv4CIDRChart_2015.pdf

So a /24 block has 255 IP addresses, 253 of those can be assigned to a computer. The remaining 2 are used by gateway and broadcast addresses

Comment: For ip 216.58.217.101, Netblock size has size 8191. (according to the site), How to get that result?